# VB.NET application deployed as IIS server to Docker migration

Tags: vb.net, docker, iis

My organization has a VB.NET application currently deployed via IIS and running on VM's. I would like to deploy this via Docker instead. I followed [this](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-windows-servercore-iis?ref=56k-cloud-blog) tutorial.

I have my Dockerfile set up as follows:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore/iis

RUN powershell -NoProfile -Command Remove-Item -Recurse C:\inetpub\wwwroot\*

WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot/RealEra

COPY / .
```

The command I use to build is:

```
docker build -t realera .
```

After running the container (and assigning a port), I get the following error:

[image: error]

I can run the application via IIS locally

Any help would be appreciated ;)

Comment: Enable IIS Manager and then you can debug this further with IIS logs and FRT, https://halfblood.pro/remote-management-of-containerized-iis-instances-on-windows-server-core-f6864c74917f

Comment: You need more information to analyze your problem, try using failed request tracing to see details about 403 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.